# It's possible to install XAMPP in a different directory?

Tags: php, xampp, webserver, localhost, prestashop-1.6

There is a way to install XAMPP in a different directory for mac? The actually directory are "Applications".

I and my colleague we have to use the same files, and we need to modify them every day in local, and later we upload them via FTP.. But it's a problem when we need to modify the same file, because my local file is different from his file, maybe recentely modified.. I know we can talk together, but maybe sometimes we could mistake..

I want to install XAMPP in a folder like the "Creative Cloud Folder" or "Onedrive" something like this, so we can modify the same files.

Comment: You should really look into subversion (svn) or some sort of a repository.

Comment: You need a version control system such as Git.